# Nodejs with Express and CORS Hanging after so many calls

Tags: node.js, express, npm, cors

So I have a Node.JS REST API which I added the CORS npm module to. Now I find that after I make so many calls, the server will hang and I have to restart it. And it's a very small number of calls too, like 6 or 7. I tried using the CORS npm module with default settings and I also tried just setting up manually like so:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
})
```

But no matter which way I do it, it's the same result. Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Here is my code for my main.js file

```js
// Imports
var express  = require('express'),
    CORS = require('cors'),
    app = express(),                               // create our app w/ express
    verRouter = express.Router(),                  // Create router for version stuff
    stageRouter = express.Router(),                // Create router for version stuff
    morgan = require('morgan'),                    // log requests to the console (express4)
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),           // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),   // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)
    winston = require('winston'),                  // logging library
    mysql = require('mysql'),                      // mysql library
    jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),                 // library to create JSON tokens for authentication
    passport = require('passport'),                // Authentication library
    LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth'),   // specific library for LDAP use
    config = require('./config/config')            // config to hold sensitive info like mysql credentials and secret key

//init logger
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)(),
    new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'versions_api.log' })
  ]
})
logger.level = 'debug'
logger.exitOnError = false

//LDAP Authentication
var eaOPTS = {
  server: {
    url: config.ldap.url,
    bindDn: config.ldap.bindDn,
    bindCredentials: config.ldap.bindCredentials,
    searchBase: config.ldap.searchBase,
    searchFilter: config.ldap.searchFilter,
    groupSearchBase: config.ldap.groupSearchBase,
    groupSearchFilter: config.ldap.groupSearchFilter,
    groupSearchAttributes: config.ldap.groupSearchAttributes
  }
}

passport.use(new LdapStrategy(eaOPTS))

// db configuration
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : config.db.host,
  user            : config.db.user,
  password        : config.db.password,
  database        : config.db.database
})

app.use(CORS(corsOpts))
app.use(morgan('dev'))                                          // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}))             // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json())                                      // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }))  // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride())

//Import the routes
var versions = require('./routes/versions')(app, pool, logger, express, jwt)
var states = require('./routes/states')(app, pool, logger, express, jwt)
var auth = require('./routes/auth')(app, logger, express, passport, jwt)


//Set up the routes
app.use('/versions', versions)
app.use('/states', states)
app.use('/auth', auth)

//Catch any 404s and print out their error message.
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if(err.status !== 404) {
    return next()
  }

  res.status(404)
  logger.error(err.message)
  console.log(err.message)
  res.send(err.message)
})

// listen (start app with nodemon main.js)
var port = process.env.PORT || 8888
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("App listening on port "+port)
})
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
As requested, here are the versions.js and state.js files:

```js
/*************************************************************************************
VERSIONS.JS
Description: Module holding all routes for the versions section of the Version REST
            API. All functions in this module handle the versions. Add a new version,
            get all versions, get a single version, update a version, search versions.
*************************************************************************************/
module.exports = function(app, pool, logger, express, jwt) {
  var helper = require("../modules/helpers")(logger)
  var router = express.Router()

  // get all versions
  router.get('/list', function(req, res, next) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
      if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
      conn.query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(st.launch_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS launch FROM versions v LEFT JOIN state_transition st ON (st.version_id=v.id)", function(err, vers) {
        if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)

        res.json(vers) // return all versions in JSON format
      })
    })
  })

  // create a version and send back all versions after creation
  router.post('/add', function(req, res, next) {
    var vals = req.body
    if(!('comment' in vals) || !('version' in vals)) {
      return helper.createErr("Comment and Version are required parameters.", res)
    }
    pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
      if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
      conn.query("SELECT * FROM versions WHERE version='"+vals.version+"'", function(err, ver) {
        if(ver.length) helper.createErr("The version "+vals.version+" already exists.")
      })
      conn.query("INSERT INTO versions(version,comment) VALUES('"+vals.version+"','"+vals.comment+"')", function(err, ver) {
        if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
        logger.info("New version added. Version: '"+vals.version+"' Comment: '"+vals.comment+"'")
        res.json({"status":"ok", "message":"Version added."})
      })
    })
  })

  // Retrieve a single version
  router.get('/:ver_id', function(req, res, next) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
      if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
      conn.query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(st.launch_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS launch FROM versions v LEFT JOIN state_transition st ON (st.version_id=v.id) WHERE v.id="+req.params.ver_id, function(err, ver) {
        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error.
        if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
        if (ver.length){
          res.json(ver)
        } else {
          return helper.createErr("No results found.", res)
        }
      })
    })
  })

  // Update a version by ID
  router.post('/edit/:ver_id', function(req, res, next) {
    var vals = req.body
    if (!req.params.ver_id) {
      return helper.createErr("Must provide a version id.", res)
    }

    pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
      if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
      conn.query("SELECT * FROM versions WHERE id="+req.params.ver_id, function(err, ver) {
        if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
        //Update the comment for the version since this is the only thing about a version we can update.
        if (ver.length) {
          conn.query("UPDATE versions SET comment='"+vals.comment+"' WHERE id="+req.params.ver_id, function(err) {
            if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
            conn.query("SELECT * FROM versions WHERE id="+req.params.ver_id, function(err, newver) {
              logger.info('Version updated from '+JSON.stringify(ver[0])+' to '+JSON.stringify(newver[0]))
              res.json({"status":"ok", "message":"Version updated."})
            })
          })
        } else {
          return helper.createErr("No results found.", res)
        }
      })
    })
  })

  //Get all versions that match the provided search criteria
  router.post('/search', function(req, res, next) {
    //version: *.*.*.***** - Search for any version that matches up to the maximum number of characters (a full version string)
    //state: Search for versions and the appropriate state transitions that match the state
    //date_start: Search for versions that have state transition(s) from the given start date (to now if no end date provided)
    //date_end: Search for version that have state transition(s) to a given end date (from a start date if provided, otherwise from the beginning of time)
    var vals = req.body
    if (Object.keys(vals).length == 0) {
      //Create an error cause we can't search for nothing.
      return helper.createErr("Must provide at least one search parameter (version, state, date start, or date end).", res)
    } else {
      pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
        if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)

        //Initialize the query and then append to it as required
        q = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(st.launch_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS launch FROM versions v LEFT JOIN state_transition st on (v.id = st.version_id) WHERE"
        if ('version' in vals) {
          q = helper.addWhere(q, " v.version LIKE '"+vals.version+"%'")
        }
        if ('state' in vals) {
          q = helper.addWhere(q, " st.state="+vals.state)
        }

        if ('date_start' in vals && !('date_end' in vals)) {
          q = helper.addWhere(q, " DATE(st.launch_date) > '"+vals.date_start+"'")
        } else if (!('date_start' in vals) && 'date_end' in vals) {
          q = helper.addWhere(q, " DATE(st.launch_date) < '"+vals.date_end+"'")
        } else if ('date_start' in vals && 'date_end' in vals) {
          q = helper.addWhere(q," DATE(st.launch_date) BETWEEN '"+vals.date_start+"' AND '"+vals.date_end+"'")
        }

        conn.query(q, function(err, vers) {
          if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
          if (vers.length) {
            res.json(vers)
          } else {
            res.json({"results": "No results found."})
          }
        })
      })//end of connection object retrieved from pool
    }
  }) //end of get "search" request)

  return router
}//end module
```

```js
/************************************************************************************
STATES.JS
Description: Module holding all routes for the state section of the Version REST API.
            All functions in this module handle the states. Add a new state, get all
            states for a given version, get a list of the states available.
************************************************************************************/
module.exports = function(app, pool, logger, express, jwt) {
  var helper = require("../modules/helpers")(logger)
  var router = express.Router()

  // Get all states (ids and names)
  router.get('/list', function(req, res) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
      if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
      conn.query("SELECT * FROM states", function(err, sts) {
        if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)

        res.json(sts)
      })
    })
  })

  //Add a new state for a version. When done, pass back the updated version with it's states.
  router.post('/add/:ver_id', function(req, res) {
    var vals = req.body
    if (!('state' in vals) || !('launch' in vals)) helper.createErr("A state and launch date are required.", res)
    pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
      if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
      conn.query("SELECT * FROM versions WHERE id="+req.params.ver_id, function(err, ver) {
        if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
        if (!ver.length) {
          //No result was found.
          return helper.createErr("A version with id +"+req.params.ver_id+" does not exist.", res)
        }
        conn.query("SELECT * FROM state_transition WHERE version_id="+ver[0].id+" AND state="+vals.state+" AND launch_date='"+vals.launch+"'", function(err, st) {
          if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
          if (st.length) return helper.createErr("The version "+ver[0].version+" already has an entry for state "+vals.state, res)
        })
        console.log("INSERT INTO state_transition(version_id,state,launch_date) VALUES("+ver[0].id+", "+vals.state+", '"+vals.launch+"')")
        conn.query("INSERT INTO state_transition(version_id,state,launch_date) VALUES("+ver[0].id+", "+vals.state+", '"+vals.launch+"')", function(err, out) {
          if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
          logger.info("New state added for version "+ver[0].version)
          res.json({"status":"ok", "message":"State added."})
        })
      })
    })
  })

  //Update the launch date of a state for a version
  router.post('/update/:ver_id/:state', function(req, res) {
    var vals = req.body
    if (!('launch_date' in vals)) helper.createErr("A launch date is required.", res)
    pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
      if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
      conn.query("SELECT * FROM versions WHERE id="+req.params.ver_id, function(err, ver) {
        if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
        if (!ver.length) {
          //No result was found.
          return helper.createErr("A version with id +"+req.params.ver_id+" does not exist.", res)
        }
        conn.query("SELECT * FROM state_transition WHERE version_id="+ver[0].id+" AND state="+req.params.state, function(err, st) {
          if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
          if (!st.length) return helper.createErr("This state does not exist yet for this version.", res)
          conn.query("UPDATE state_transition SET launch_date='"+vals.launch_date+"' WHERE version_id="+ver[0].id+" AND state="+req.params.state, function(err, out) {
            if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
            logger.info("Launch date updated.")
            res.json({"status":"ok", "message":"Launch date updated."})
          })
        })

      })
    })
  })

  // Get a state and it's name by the id.
  router.get('/:state', function(req, res) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
      if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)
      conn.query("SELECT * FROM states WHERE state_id="+req.params.state, function(err, sts) {
        if (err) return helper.handleErr(err, res)

        res.json(sts[0])
      })
    })
  })

  return router
}
```

Comment: FYI, I don't see a definition for `corsOpts` in this line `app.use(CORS(corsOpts))`.  Also, why create`verRouter` and `stageRouter` and not use them?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't doing something like leaking a database connection and thus exhausting the connection pool?  You only disclose the code that creates the connection pool, not the code that uses it so we can't tell from the code you have disclosed.

Comment: Where'd you go?  I offered an idea shortly after you posted and now you appear to be gone!  Stack Overflow works best if you don't just post and disappear for awhile.  It's much more interactive than other sites and your **main** opportunity to have people see and answer your question is in the first 30-60 minutes after posting.  If you're not around to engage with people in that time period, you will potentially miss much of your opportunity to get help, particularly if your question requires some back and forth before it can be answered.

Comment: Apologies, I posted during work hours and it was shortly before leaving and now today has been busy. Also I didn't get an email for some reason.

So I trimmed out some stuff I had in there for testing, which included that corsOpts variable. I don't actually use that, just initialize with cors() default. 

The reason I believe it's a CORS issue is because I had this all set up without the LDAP authorisation and therefore did not have CORS set up and this never happened. But as soon as I added CORS this started happening. I can post my other routes if they will help, though.

Comment: Well, many people will not engage further in questions that have 24 hour turn-around time.  Way too inefficient for this type of site.  In the future, I'd suggest you only post when you can actually check the site several times in the next hour.  That's how this site works best for both people posting questions and people providing answers.

Comment: What about my suggestion that it might be something related to the connection pool?  CORS doesn't really do much do your code, but add a couple headers to responses as an instruction to browsers.

Comment: Hence my confusion. It shouldn't do anything that kills the server like that. But as I said, it doesn't happen if I shut CORS off. I can't personally see where there could be any leaking going on, however I will update my original post with the versions and states routes in case I may be missing something.

Comment: So I did some more testing based around your idea and it looks like, as this is my first time writing a node.js app, there was a conn.release() function that I should have been using inside my mysql pool connections before I send my response. Apparently I must have missed that while doing my research on that function :( Thank you for your help and pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my guess turned out to be the issue, I'll put this in an answer so you can close out the question.

Your symptoms sound like maybe you are not closing a connection (returning it to the connection pool) so after a few requests, the connection pool is empty and the server just sits there waiting for a connection to be available.